# How to show video files in UITableView with image of video?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, alassetslibrary, mpmediapickercontroller

I could access mediafiles with `MPMediaPickerController`, I need to list down all videos I selected from picker.

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` is being used and I have added a player to every cell, but I couldn't use it for more than one cell. I think! on selecting the UITableViewCell on UITableView, we need to use this. But how to show the thumbnail or image of video (footprint) in tableview for all cells.

**Goal**: Once I list down with footprint, on selecting I use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play selected.

Thanks,
Venkatarao

Answer (score 0):

- Store the ALAsset URL of selected videos
- Load the UITableView wit the
  all selected videos thumbnail(using ALAsset URL).
- UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath,
  retrive the ALAsset url from your local directory and play it via
  MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: I found set of things meanwhile. We could show and play media files in UIWebView as well. Its just that we have static instance of MPMoviePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks are:

1. Listing
2. Playing

Approaches:

1. We could list if we have access to `ALAsset`(through `assetURL`), we
   could get the thumbNail and use on `UITableView`. We could put custom
   play buttons on the views. Upon selection we use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to organize the file
   from selected assetURL
2. Using UIWebView, we embed `UIWebview` on `UITableViewCell` and pass on assetURL. Specify embed type un HTML string for webWiew as `application/x-shockwave-flash` and it will use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to organize file upon selection.

Thanks&Regards,
Venkatatarao N